# How to make a call one android device to other device which was connected same wifi network?

Tags: android, wifi, p2p, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I need make call from one device to another device through WiFi.Both devices connected to same WiFi. Which protocol I have to use for this requirement. Both are android devices, Connected to same WiFi router and make call one to other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **Network Service Discovery** you can connect devices via WiFi router.

More info about NSD here: https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html

Then you can make VoIP using open source VOIP projects:

http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/

http://www.linphone.org/

http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/

And here is API to do SIP. It's used to make and answer VOIP calls: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/package-summary.html

Comment: Let me try this.Thanking you. Deserve 1+.