# How to implement audio calls in flutter app for devices connected to same wifi?

Tags: flutter, sockets, flutter-dependencies, audio-streaming, wifip2p

I have been trying to develop a flutter app that allows devices communicate over same wifi network. The main goal is to add audio call(More like a walkie talkie). I want the router to be center point for communication instead of any server, so the call works even if there is no interent. Because connecting to same wifi network I guess it will provide more coverage rather than wifi-direct or hotspot connections.

I have implemented the Network Seervice Discovery where each app instance registers a new service and can also detect new services registered by other devices. I have gone through a few things on the Android Dev website but could not find anything for flutter. I can not get it how to connect to the other device and start communicating. I have a few examples where apps(android only) are using sockets to communicate but their communication is client-server however mine(as I think) is client-client communication.

I found this similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46191661/how-to-make-a-call-one-android-device-to-other-device-which-was-connected-same-w), but it is for android only I could not find any walkthrough for flutter.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.